# Newline does not work on textarea replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, newline

I'm trying to replace a word in a textarea with another text, but I cannot seem to get newlines to work.

```
<input type="text" id="testing" value="Newline \n test" /><br />
<textarea>test</textarea><br />
<button>Test</button>

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("textarea").text($("textarea").text().replace(/test/g, $("#testing").val()));
});
```

Press the button. It will not replace the \n with a new line. I tried `<br />`, `<br>` (incorrect HTML), `%0A` and `&#13;&#10;` but it still does not work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9P7XU/)

Comment: Unrelated side note, `<br>` is not incorrect HTML. It's incorrect XHTML, but ok to use with HTML5 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the character string '\n' (2 characters '\','n') with the actual \n line break character.

This should do what you need.

```
var textBoxline = $("#testing").val().replace(/\\n/g, '\n');                                
$("textarea").text($("textarea").text().replace(/test/g, textBoxline));
```

You will still need to make allowances for leading/trailing spaces around the \n itself.